# Java Sockets: check if client is able to receive message from server

Tags: java, sockets

When I `flush()` the message from the server's `OutputStream`, the client either received message or not (if it was disconnected before timeout). I need to somehow control this situation from server-side, I have to know if client is able to receive the message before sending it. How it could be done?

Comment: If you need to know whether or not a message has been delivered completely over TCP/IP then you need to send some kind of ACK message back from the client.

Comment: So for example this ACK message could be time the message was sent, right? If the client receives the message, sends the same time message to server and this way the server knows that the message was received. The problem is that I can't easily modify the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I have typically used a blocking read in a separate thread to read client messages and disseminate them as needed.

If the client disconnects, the [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) operation returns -1 and we take that as notification that the client has "disconnected" and the InputStream should be closed. It may also throw an IOException if the connection is abnormally terminated.

You can then test [Socket.isClosed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed--) to verify whether or not you can still write messages.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. One more question: should that separate thread be using the same InputStream as the main thread?

Comment: You should do all your reading from the other thread. You could potentially manage your logic all in a single thread if you don't need to write to the client asynchronously. Outer loop blocks on the read, inner loop writes the response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using a TCP/IP connection:

TCP is a connection oriented protocol: any time a <strike>message</strike> packet is sent the receiver must respond with an acknowledgement (this protocol is under the application layer, so if no error is thrown you can assume the message was received).
There is no way to know if a message will be received before sending it, but you can assume that if the connection is alive it will work.

Comment: Yes, it's TCP/IP connection. The problem is that the error is not thrown, it looks like the message was delivered but it was not. The Input/Output Streams and the Socket itself are not closed. This situation arises when the client disconnects from the Internet before the timeout

Comment: TCP "messages" are not acknowledged. Individual packets get ACKS.

Comment: @justasd But if the client is suddenly disconnected server should throw a timeout sooner or later (unless timeout is set to infinite time)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the message could be sent after the client disconnect and before the timeout. If it was sent in this ~30sec interval, the message is not received.

Comment: If client and server are both in the same intranet you can try to set a lower timeout (not sure what is the minimum safe value)