# Jersey/Servlet Serverside handling of network failures

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, servlet-3.0

*-- EDIT: --*

*To rephrase the question.
Does HTTP know anything about the status of underlying TCP connection?
TCP is a reliable protocol. When the server sends data to the client it expects an acknowledgment signal from that client. What happens in HTTP when the underlying server side TCP connection fails to receive the ACK signal?*

*-- ORIGINAL Question: --*

I am trying to solve a design issue on our HTTP client/server app.
Here is the situation:

- The server runs on Tomcat, and we are somewhat limited to using Jersey or Servlets for the server side implementation.
- The client requests data from the Server, which **once read is deleted**.
- Data **must not be deleted** if the client has not received it.
- There is **no confirmation** from the client if the data is received or not.
- The client impl **cannot** be changed in any way.
- The **network** connection is **unstable** and can be interrupted for long periods of time (e.g. 30 sec.) and also often.

The problem: if the client made a request and shortly after lost connection to the server, the **server will not recognize** this and **it will delete and send** the data to the client over the dead connection.

Ideally, we want to get an IOException when flushing the data stream to the client and handle it accordingly:

```
    try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()) {
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: do something ...
    }
```

I simulated this locally by killing the client shortly after sending the request or by setting a very low client read timeout value. In both cases I got a server side exception (with bioth Jersey and Servlets).

The last test was sending a request over a network and pulling the network cable in the process.
Unfortunately I did not get the expected result. The server streamed the data back without recognizing the interrupted connection.

So, does anyone have an idea how to force a Server side exception when the connection to the client is broken?

Any other ideas that don't involve using Sockets or confirmation calls from the client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the file in real time, you can write a message on a queue in order to delete it later. The delete would have to check a database where you write if the client received the file completely.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately your suggestion requires client side changes which are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to know for certain whether the data arrived to the client unless the client sends an acknowledgement message.

The only solution seems to be not actually deleting the data, but keeping it and setting a 'deleted' flag. But since I don't know the particular use case, I'm not sure if this helps...

Comment: Well the client does send an acknowledgement message on TCP level. I was hoping this information is propagated upwards.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a two way protocol.

If you set up an input stream and call `InputStream.read()`, this should return -1 if the client has disconnected.

More detail here:

[Java Sockets: check if client is able to receive message from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739088/java-sockets-check-if-client-is-able-to-receive-message-from-server)

Comment: Thanks for the dedication :) However, the problem I am facing is on the Server, not the client. Respectively I tried using OutputStream.push() and OutputStream.flush() in order to force an exception whie writing the output to the client. Unfrotunately it does not happen.

Comment: I understand, but try setting up an InputStream (which you won't need to read any actual data from) on the server, as if the client would send data.

Comment: Oh I see, interesting. I will try it ASAP , unfortunately I am currently on a very long vacation and I’ll have access to my laptop in mid May. Thanks a lot, this suggestion sounds promising!